# How to say no politely and friendly to recommendations from waiters/staffs at a restaurant/cafe?

Tags: politeness

I am not a native English speaker and have a question about alternative expressions for "no thank you" especially in a Cafe/restaurant.

When I order something over a counter or at a table, sometimes staffs/waiters friendly offer some recommendations like "How would you like today's soup with?" or "Would you like to try new dark chocolate cookies?"　with good smiles.

I know the best response to their friendliness is to order their recommendations but most of the time I cannot. I do my best to express my appreciation saying "no thank you" with a regretful smile but I always feel bad about my poor vocabulary.

Could you tell me any friendly expressions other than "no thank you" that I can use in that situation?

Comment: "No thank you" is quite common and perfectly acceptable; there's nothing impolite or inarticulate about it. :)

Comment: "Not today, thanks" or "No thank you, not today."  is another alternative. It is more tentative, and perhaps less honest, but sometimes pretending like it was at least something interesting is a bit of a softer way to reject something. If you want to be more conversational you could tell them why ... "I'm sorry, I'm on a budget",  "I wish I could, but I'm on a diet", "They really look good, but I'm going to have a big dinner".. but "No thank you" is absolutely fine.

Comment: Instead of 'no thank you' you can say 'thank you, no'.

Comment: Hi Nina.  There is a new stack exchange dedicated to interpersonal communication skills.  You might have a better time receiving a comprehensive answer there than on EL&U:  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, Nina! You should go to [interpersonal.se], Nina. Ask there.

Answer (score 4):

It is not at all rude or impolite to say "No, thank you", but if you feel uncomfortable doing so, just look at the waiter and smile broadly as you say it. The staff are not necessarily offering you something extra for your benefit: they are more-than-likely instructed to do so by management to add to your bill, so even a firm "No, thank you" is not going to cause any offence at all.

Comment: +1 for noting that this behaviour is usually _not_ "just being friendly" but is usually trying to up-sell more product. As such, OP should rarely feel "guilt" for declining their suggestions.